# How to parametrically express a parametric plane curve of a 3D plot as an axis in different 2D plot?

Tags: curves, parametric

## Preface

Consider a plane curve defined by parametric equations (for $t_1\le t \le t_2$):

$$x=x\left(t\right)$$
$$y=y\left(t\right)$$

In addition, there is a scalar function $f\left(x,y\right)$ defined for every value of $x$ and $y$.

Giving an example to illustrate (in this example, $t$ is the central angle in the $x,y$ plane):
$$x\left(t\right)=\cos\left(t\right)$$
$$y\left(t\right)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\left(t\right)}$$
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\cos^2\left(\pi * 6 * x * y\right)$$

The parametric curve, and the value of $f\left(x,y\right)$ along that curve, can be depicted in a 3D plot (in this example, for the range $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$), expressed something like:
$$ParametricPlot3D\left[x\left(t\right), y\left(t\right), f\left(x,y\right) \right]$$

and depicted graphically as:

[image: f(x,y) along curve s(x,y)]

I'll choose one segment $s\left(t\right)$ of this curve to simplify the example (e.g. for the range $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq t\leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$):

[image]

## Objective

My objective is to plot the values of $f\left(x,y\right)$ along the curve segment $s\left(t\right)$ as a 2D parametric plot.  That is, with the curve $s\left(t\right)$ "straightened out" to be the horizontal axis of the 2D plot, and with the vertical axis being the value of $f\left(x,y\right)$ -- for example, something like this:

[image: f(x,y) vs. s(t)]

## Question

My question is, how do I express the curve segment $s\left(t\right)$ in parametric form as the horizontal axis (clumsy description, but not sure how else to state the concept)?  I am guessing the form may be related to the differential for the arc length of $s\left(t\right)$:
$$ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

But that may be way off the mark.

I think that the length of $s$ would, for any curve, be $\ge$ the length of the parallel projection of $s$ onto the $x-f\left(x,y\right)$ plane, and so I'd expect the length of $s$ as the horizontal axis in a 2D plot to be $\ge$ the length of that parallel projection of $s$.

I am expecting there is an expression $S\left(t\right)$ for displacement on the horizontal axis such that each point on the horizontal axis represents a corresponding point on the curve $s$, so that a 2D parametric plot might look something like:
$$ParametricPlot2D\left[S\left(t\right), f\left(x,y\right) \right]$$

A further constraint on $S\left(t\right)$ would be, I believe, that the following would hold true for both the arc length of $s\left(t\right)$ and $S\left(t\right)$ over the interval $t1\leq t\leq t2$:
$$S\left(t2\right) - S\left(t1\right) = \int_{t1}^{t2}{s\left(t\right)dt}$$

Maybe this suggests that the following is true?
$$S\left(t\right)=\int{s\left(t\right)dt}$$

I can certainly provide any additional clarification if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For your parametric plot, your $x$ coordinate as a function of $t$ should be the length traversed along the curve between time $t_1$ and $t$. This is:

$$\int_{w = t_1}^{w = t} ds = \int_{w = t_1}^{w = t} \sqrt{\left(x'(w)\right)^2+\left(y'(w)\right)^2}dw$$

Comment: In this case, t represents a central angle in the x-y plane (rather than time).  The definite integral you show would yield a single scalar value (the arc length), but I need a *function* that describes position along the plane curve as a function of t, for t1<=t<=t2.  I am thinking now that the indefinite integral provides exactly this function.

Comment: I've fixed the bounds. Note that the upper bound is $t$, so the overall expression is a function of $t$, giving you the partial arc length between $t_1$ and $t$ for any $t$.

Comment: OK, so would you then agree that, more generally, the functional expression for displacement along the plane curve in terms of t would just be the indefinite integral defining S(t) in my statement of the question above?  Or would that not strictly be true?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting 3d and development for quarter circle:
EDIT:
$$ x= \cos t1, y=\sin t1, t= \tan^{-1}(y/x)= \tan^{-1}(\tan t_1 ) =t_1 $$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that plots f(x,y) w.r.t. variation in the parametric variable t, rather than w.r.t. variation in position on the curve.

Comment: @Dave In your example it happens that $t$ **is** the position along the curve (specifically, distance counterclockwise from the point $(1,0)$). Perhaps a different example would have been better.

Comment: Edited.. Should I use another symbol to be clearer?

Comment: @DavidK - I see what you mean.  Indeed for the example of y(t) that I provided, the position along the parametric curve *is* t itself, and so it wasn't the best choice to illustrate the question.

Comment: @Narasimham I am seeing that in fact your answer was appropriate for the example I gave.  But I think the more general solution is indeed the indefinite integral mentioned in the question above, would you agree?